# Waterwheel - Is a bigger or smaller pulley advantagous

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, torque

We have a 14ft overshot waterwheel, it is calculated will generate roughly 5hp. It has oak spokes going to cast iron hubs on an oak shaft.

We want to fit a pulley to it to drive some machinery.

It has an oak shaft / axle at the centre with steel sleeve and gudgeons on the end of the shaft which rest in some soft metal bearings.

We have been told the twisting forces on the current set-up are too large to drive things from the gudgeons at the centre of the axle/ shaft.

So the suggestion is to mount a large pulley on the side of the hubs / spokes. We have two pulley size options 1000mm and 1250mm.

Question I have is: Is it better to put a 1000mm or 1250mm pulley on the side. Obviously the larger 1250mm one will help with the gearing. but what are the other considerations / impacts of choosing one over the other.

[image: Rough sketch]